# Unable to construct RTCIceCandidate from candidate string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

**Chrome**.

ICE candidate string generatred on computer A (taken directly from the SDP attribute "candidate"):

```
candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.X.1 65398 typ host generation 0 ufrag XBYY network-id 2
```

Now that is passed through signaling, to be received on computer B.

computer B received (iceStr):

```
candidate:2999745851 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.X.1 65398 typ host generation 0 ufrag XBYY network-id 2
```

and tries to `let candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(iceStr)`

This results in

> TypeError: Failed to construct 'RTCIceCandidate': cannot convert to
> dictionary.

Computer B does so in order to perform

```
addIceCandidate(candidate)
```

on the RTCPeerConnection object.

yet, due to the prior error, unable to proceed.

**Reproducable example**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 let c ='candidate:2445384676 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.26 57088 typ host generation 0 ufrag z1J2 network-id 1 network-cost 10';
 let candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(c);
</script>
```

Ideas?

All the official code samples and docs instruct to send that very parameter to remote peer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onicecandidate

Then there's some confusion with deprecation (constructed under the hood by other functions it seems ) and JSON encoding so which one is it.

From the official samples:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling

```
    function handleNewICECandidateMsg(msg) {
  var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(msg.candidate);

  myPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate)
    .catch(reportError);
}
```

The value seems to be also passed directly to   `var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(msg.candidate);` which ends up as an exercise in futility (same error).

**UPDATE:** Looks like the API only understands a String OBJECT  (which is sort of a pitty considering the EVENT contains a primitive type!) i.e.
reproducable sample

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 let c = new String('candidate:2445384676 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.26 57088 typ host generation 0 ufrag z1J2 network-id 1 network-cost 10');
 let candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(c);
</script>
```

But, even then Chrome produces an exception

> TypeError: Failed to construct 'RTCIceCandidate': sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex are both null.

There seem to be other 'doubtful' things..like the  WebRTC offer contains  platform-specific new-line characters.

RTCSessionDescription cannot be instantiated directly from SDP offer returned from event since it's a PRIMITIVE type and RTCSessionDescription() wants String OBJECT. Additionally, the primitive type cannot be easily converted to String since it contains platform specific new-lines and thus simple new String(SDP) results in a malformed String Object.

anyone?

**UPDATE** In case of the WebRTC offer, the documentation does not state that one needs to provide an explicit JSON object to RTCSessionDescription containing both the type (lame 'offer' string) and SDP fields. Which sort of implicitly forces the use of JSON  (inefficient encoding) in the first place throughout the signaling process. (were one no to reconstruct the lame fields on his own but then this contradicts the black-box attitude all over the place)

Answer (score 5):

You are trying with just the candidate string instead of the full object which also includes the sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex properties, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceCandidate

You can construct a RTCIceCandidate object as

```
new RTCIceCandidate({
  candidate: 'candidate:2445384676 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.26 57088 typ host generation 0 ufrag z1J2 network-id 1 network-cost 10',
  sdpMid: 'something', // don't make it up, you get this in onicecandidate
  sdpMLineIndex: 12345, // don't make it up, you get this in onicecandidate
})
```

or you call

```
pc.addIceCandidate({  
  candidate: 'candidate:2445384676 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.26 57088 typ host generation 0 ufrag z1J2 network-id 1 network-cost 10',
  sdpMid: 'something', // don't make it up, you get this in onicecandidate
  sdpMLineIndex: 12345, // don't make it up, you get this in onicecandidate
})
```

The same applies to RTCSessionDescription objects.

Comment: Let us hold our horses. THEN the documentation is AT LEAST confusing. It states both in samples AND in writing: "(The remote peer, upon receiving the candidate, will add the candidate to its candidate pool by calling addIceCandidate(), passing in the candidate *string *you have passed along using the signaling server.) " Nowhere does it even suggest the need of passing additional fields. OR the use of toJSON() in order for these fields to be serialized were one NOT to prefer JSON over BER for instance.

Comment: While this might work, the official samples/tutorials  do not do any kind of that 'magic', nor do they employ toJSON() for the additional field to be included. Nor do they suggest that a JSON object is to be passed into the constructor.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/icecandidate_event#Sharing_a_new_candidate dedicated section states a string needs to be shared. Nowhere does it state the need for or where sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex parameters are to be found.

Comment: IF authors of the docs are to uphold the 'string needs to be exchanged'  they should at least suggest the exchange of  THE RESULT OF JSON.stringify() which does indeed produce a STRING containing the needed fields. OR that additional fields ARE required were developers not to use JSON. THAT information is nowhere to be found nor is it present within code-samples.

Comment: hands full of work (like all of us) will try to do so, once we get past current implementation run.